# Xero authorization via ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, xero-api

I want to authorize customer xero accounts via an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. Is this possible?

How I can I redirect the user to Xero authorization page? I am trying to do this in Swagger. I am getting following error

> Failed to fetch.
> Possible Reasons:
>
> CORS
> Network Failure
> URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.